# Edit text between two lines using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to change this text

```
PortNumber=10001
;UserName=xxxxxxxxx
;Password=xxxxxxxxx
CiPdfPath=xxxxx
```

into this

```
PortNumber=10001
UserName=xxxxxxxxx
Password=xxxxxxxxx
CiPdfPath=xxxxx
```

I cannot simply search for `;Username=xxxx` and `;Password=xxxx` because they exist multiple times in the file and need to be commented on some places.

I found the next command

```
$file = Get-Content "Test.ini" -raw
$file -replace "(?m)^PortNumber=10001[\n\r]+;UserName=xxxx[\r\n]+;Password=xxxx","PortNumber=10001 `r`nUserName=xxxxx`r`nPassword=xxxxx"
```

And it worked!
But maybe it can be simplyfied

Answer (score 1):

If you use the (?ms) (multiline-singleline) option and here-strings, you can do most of the work with copy/paste:

```
$string = 
@'
PortNumber=10001
;UserName=xxxxxxxxx
;Password=xxxxxxxxx
CiPdfPath=xxxxx
'@


$regex = 
@'
(?ms)PortNumber=10001
;UserName=xxxxxxxxx
;Password=xxxxxxxxx
CiPdfPath=xxxxx
'@

$replace = 
@'
PortNumber=10001
UserName=xxxxxxxxx
Password=xxxxxxxxx
CiPdfPath=xxxxx
'@

$string -replace $regex,$replace
PortNumber=10001
UserName=xxxxxxxxx
Password=xxxxxxxxx
CiPdfPath=xxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks, but i had to edit a bunch of ini files. so i made a made a loop.  ``Get-Content "D:\inifile-$location" -Raw | ForEach-Object { 
$_ -replace "(?m)^PortNumber=10001[\n\r]+;UserName=xxxx[\r\n]+;Password=xxxx","PortNumber=10001 `r`nUserName=xxxxx`r`nPassword=xxxxx" } | 
  Set-Content "D:\inifile-$location-new" } ``

Comment: Either method will can be utilized in a loop. If it's being used in a script, I think the here-strings make it a lot more intuitive to see exctly what's being matched and replaced, and easier to maintain if you need to make adjustments to the regex  or  the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you search full text which you'd like to replace? 
So find:

```
PortNumber=10001
;UserName=xxxxxxxxx
;Password=xxxxxxxxx
CiPdfPath=xxxxx
```

and replace with:

```
PortNumber=10001
UserName=xxxxxxxxx
Password=xxxxxxxxx
CiPdfPath=xxxxx
```

You can use regular expression to express irrelevant characters
http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html
http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions

Comment: yeah i'm trying to do it with regular expression but i cannot get the right command. :(

Comment: Found it, see the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex.

Or even simpler, depending on your requirement;

If you know the linenumber of the lines you want to replace, you could easily do this do replace the certain lines:

Given that the file format is the text you've pasted (e.g. username on line 2 and password on line 3), read the file into a line buffer. Replace line 2 and 3 and set the content back to the file.

```
$lines=(Get-Content .\Test.txt)
$lines[1]= $lines[1].Replace(";","")
$lines[2]= $lines[2].Replace(";","")
$lines|Set-Content .\Test.txt
```

Comment: The line numbers are not always the same :(

Comment: If the line numbers are different, and you cannot use regex to replace all instances of ";password", how are you manually determining what lines to replace? There must be some pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstading the nature of the question but are you not simply trying to remove the leading semicolons? Is it important to seach for those strings exclusivley?

```
$file = Get-Content "Test.ini" -raw
$file -replace "(?sm)^;"
$file -replace "(?smi)^;(?=(username|password))"
```

Both examples should produce the same output. The first will match all leading semicolons. The second will match leading semicolons if the are followed, using a lookahead, by either username or password.

Comment: Well the ini files contains more usernames and passwordss who need to be commented. Only the username and password under PortNumber=10001 needs to be uncommented.